# The contacts I save in my lava X1 grand gets automatically saved in another android Micromax canvas .. How to solve this problem?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

The contacts added or deleted in one device gets automatically added or deleted in the other .

Comment: Did both device uses same Google account? Then turn off sync, in settings->accounts->Google (uncheck , contacts)

Answer (score 0):

If you logged in your google account on both of the devices. It automatically syncs your People details in both device.
If you add one contact in your lava it will automatically gets updated in all the devices which you logged in.
So sign out from the another device or turn off the sync.